# How to print value of a hashmap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

When I execute the below code:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value));
```

I get `15234:[com.org.myprj.Dashboard@18a6be14]` as sysout.

How to I get object value in hashmap? Here object is a row inserted in arraylist.

Comment: Take a look at duplicate question (linked at top of this page - you may need to refresh it to see it). In short, override `public String toString(){..}` method inside `Dashboard` class to generate string which you want to see while printing `Dashboard` instance in sysout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement overridden toString method in object

example

```
class Dashboard{   
    private double re, im; 

    public Dashboard(double re, double im) { 
        this.re = re; 
        this.im = im; 
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return String.format(re + " + i" + im); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: @Aziz... i have updated answer..kindly check

Comment: Why `return String.format(re + " + i" + im);`? Why not `return re + " + i" + im;`?

Comment: @Pshemo.. Thanks for input.. that was one of the example... OP can use his own version on how he want to see data...